# How can I augment/merge the prototype of class with a mapped type?

Tags: typescript

This is a reduced example of what I'm trying to do:

```
function Base<T extends Record<string, Function>>(record: T) {
    class X {
        constructor() { }
    }
    // (A)  All the function of the record added to the prototype.
    // (In reality I use `Objet.defineProperty` or something similar
    // but that is not important to this question).
    Object.assign(X.prototype, record)

    // (???)  How do I type this so TS knows C.prototype has more member?

    return X;
}

// (B)  Derived inherits from the return of Base while providing
// some functions `foo` and `bar` that Derived will "inherit".
class Derived extends Base({
    foo: () => 42,
    bar: () => "hi"
}) {
    // (C)  I want to be able to override a function here
    override bar() {
        return "bye";
    }
}

const inst = new Derived();

// (D)  Will print `42, "bye"` but TS doesn't know .foo()
console.log(inst.foo(), inst.bar())
```

Again, this is reduced example, in my code `Base` derives the methods that it will put in the prototype based on the given record, and the type that I need TS to know is a mapped type based on `T`, something like `Transformed<T>`; I'll put an slightly more complete example at the end.

Of course this code, as it is, fails in TS in `(C)` and `(D)` since it cannot know that I'm modifying the prototype in `(A)`. The question is then, how?

This is what I've tried:

**Attempt 1**: Declaration merging of `X` inside `Base`:

This basically represents what I want TS to know, that `X` has the members of `T`, the only issue is it doesn't work:

```
function Base<T extends Record<string, Function>>(record: T) {
    class X { constructor() { } }
    Object.assign(X.prototype, record)

    // Trying to use declaration merging here...
    // ERROR: Interface 'X' incorrectly extends interface 'T'.
    interface X extends T {}

    return X;
}
```

**Attempt 2**: A type assertion in the return of `Base` to a constructor function with an instance of `T`:

```
function Base<T extends Record<string, Function>>(record: T) {
    class X { constructor() { } }
    Object.assign(X.prototype, record)

    // Type assertion here...
    return X as new () => X & T;
}
```

This mostly works and is (more or less) what I'm doing know, the issue is that TS thinks that the members of `T` are part of an *instance* of `X` instead of its *prototype*. That difference matters in `(C)` if a tried to override a method inside `Derived`:

```
class Derived extends Base({
    foo: ():number => 42,
    bar: ():string => "hi"
}) {
    // (C)  I want to be able to override a function here, but
    // ERROR: Class 'Base<{ foo: () => number; bar: () => string; }>.X & { foo: () => number; bar: () => string; }'
    // defines instance member property 'bar', but extended class 'Derived' defines
    // it as instance member function.
    override bar() {
        return "bye";
    }
}
```

I can make this work using a function as a field in `Derived` instead of a method, but that is not ideal since now I'm creating a new function on every instance instead of once in the prototype.

**Attempt 3**: A type assertion in the return of `Base` to `typeof X & { prototype: X & T}`:

Here I'm trying to describe that the elements of `T` will be only part of the prototype of `X`, at least that is the idea.

```
function Base<T extends Record<string, Function>>(record: T) {
    class X { constructor() { } }
    Object.assign(X.prototype, record)

    // Type assertion here...
    return X as typeof X & { prototype: X & T };
}
```

However this doesn't work either and I'm not that sure why. It's like TS now requires that `Derives` implements `T` by itself, which is clearly not what I intended. You can see a [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAIQIYGcCmAeAKozADykzABN1EAlTCOAJzO3SnpjAHMAaRAMXGjwwAPmEAKerQZkAXIlwBKRAG8AUIg2IIAGwyUAGivWaTdMC3ohoDMUuWIAvsY1OTAejeIxAQSWJv2tqIUAAWmIigkLAIiHDAwWGIknSMiKhkZJhkwXAJ4QAO9HBQxQCe+ZgAdM6IHl4AkkiSqNowUKWI9YggWIgABgDyAEYAVphQlZnA7JgACkUV9O19sfSI6HAAtuMh7BzrMJswuvQ1dUMgUAmoVzCUYMWIh-kMUKhgVyUJd4gAjiCYFhCBTVEzDMbQSp6GAcMBifSVQrFMoVHjJaQKVRnTxiAD8+L8AAk4AB3RBkXJddoVb6UDbyADKiAA1g8SZQAMKIoolanhEIYRCbBjhbabIaYei4rHuTy4eilPZpJB6SXRJBhSSVbU1SRQED0JCGQV8uKIQwAMhUiCRvPKmDklvkjgA3KonKo6mJkH4ACKSmAANyyTzAmralGARU2eSS4wNSDNaF6JN22gKRUDMDIe09ng22wiAnVlD6wDgcBW72yfSGqHoK1CN0Q-rYweyJOOQQAROxw1Bu9UdHoWwH2wRiKQKCgMJgxGoTOW4HJbHIwCBxZLEABeYSIAAsACYuDU6-QVwo5BYlbvEN3dt33XZsV4OX4uiT3p9chK0kN0zksTBvQbCZGkRZREIiCapgNRwMBoHhGethGCYJh6gmd5DKUmDdm6JhOB6ZgsKGJHbogYCYGSrZBlkthunmXi+n4ADqXY2mwHz9EePDdthuErBcVy4EyFKAmAADkVysqSiCVEutiqMRcDppU2hwBwYjsCw8kVrYPDaRMyEKJiQA)

---

EDIT: Addressing the comment, here is an slightly more complete example: [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqALpApsgngB3QSVKgB44DGSyA9qLKutAHYEBuqAThqFqxTq0hxQBmyNKADm0FvQBQIUK1QkKrACagARqgA2FAO4A6UAAMAQgEMaR0LuhatoFW0nozoeql2hBAV3ploFIwoZuQ2dgT0at5YsmAMIuhcFEjJ2OhCCfKoSN6s7mokWhbwABRGhFZh9pqgrgDW9HpBaQA0saAAVt6w5GgKLQhBMPBEZgC2WFqoA9BIAOTwjeTQE8pIZvRI+gCU0vw4oABijAC8oCWEAFygAN4AvtugJwB8oL4NTQDc0ntpEKwbWCCZRjVAqAA84AIhCQqEi8AASoplBCeqwGGIBsdnq8zjdpKBQHIoIgfH4kAFmgcqhp0CgXGRvGZ7Ps6ENEtwUqz9ASiWASgA5ZJ0ciNTwqCioWD0ObkdZ1FysMTeUGbWDbHmEgDaAGlBqAFRgMuAALrXEqPF6gJE5PLgNLg7HSO4-Mn+QKgcw0SHQ2Hw63I1TgtEYrH0HElBRKVTXcCPfGEwrFUAADVuvMTgTR3jIygtt1ALsJRa8ynOSnoPVAWsNA0E9BNoAyAHl1B1FFs4Uh0VLI4GVNt4xnQK322R9I5BAxUAAFbi8fglFP6JJc1oG1AYAYJwm7pjM7yofM73e7uQACTYeDmYwcTiYGMyCmZXl87qGIWstmq6En05Uw6nnI8T0pwnKpAcGRGCmRiGAAyhQoKQHooD4JAZgsKAfR0qI+5aIegFnmAwSirQKjwCktKcMUYKUMY9ZWCU2EIIsyQIKsfAbEgGqEYSCi2ow9YlPc2zfKexbDg8YmFj8hJyPgRCkHKVA1GY6hTHR-G5IwsCIdkMD0GIoBaNACoiHAAzqN45BTBShkQHBBpirycgkf8gLAqwoIQuAryIGYjLMloHAgaIq4QdMbhsaBDA9BsJBSpqWQCamtSLB45yWq8aYAGTuZWnneZCzzfC60hJrA8AACL3rRRB+uRnoWEeO7AhQ5pZaAAAsABMbSEuoZisB1TyvAARDAY3OkOhIUCwrDoo4GhDcefKgOCAC0oAAKILWW2HDlpeSgGN6gYKgY3SS6ZUVlWsXkGc7ieDV6IsCoFrfO0JRVY8oAAOrfmBDDkEYvUDKd51jVYVnkOAjkSlKMrkB8nj6G1FrlVmFBTPoOhiCU91oxQFAWjMlZbINrAWtsQA). The key main difference with the previous initial snippet here is that I show an example of a mapped type `Transformed<T>` which describes the type of the properties I actually want in the prototype of `X`.

```
type Fn = (x: {}) => unknown;
type Transformed<T extends Record<string, Fn>> = {
  // This function type will be the actual type in the prototype.
  [K in keyof T]: () => ReturnType<Fn>
}
```

---

#### Questions

Now, after all this context, this are the specific questions I have:

1. In general, how can I augment/merge the type of a class with some mapped type `T`?

   This is an issue I end up having a lot of times: I have some computed type `T`, usually a mapped type or a constrained generic and I want to augment the type of a class with it; the previous example is just a concrete example of such a situation.
2. In this specific example, how can I type `Base` (or `X`) so that TS knows that its return value is a class with the properties of `T` in its *prototype*?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Does using the return type `{ new (): T }` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqqajm) meet your needs?

Comment: @jsejcksn That is very interesting. It seems that the change in the return type doesn't make any difference: I changed it to `new () => X & T` and that still works; it's the use of a method syntax in `T` (as opposed to using the arrow syntax) which makes it work. [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mbyO4N) I edited your example to explain exactly what I mean. Basically, using `foo() { return ... }` instead of `foo: () => ...`. I never noticed that, thank you. However, this doesn't solve my issue...

Comment: @jsejcksn ... the problem is that I actually don't need `new () => X & T` but `new () => X & Transformed<T>`, where `Transformed<T>` is a (isomorphic) mapped type that returns a new function type for every `keyof T`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAPARN). This is still a very minimal example, the way my function derives the actual implementation is more complex and the function changes its signature completely. I'll edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77518782/how-can-i-augment-merge-the-prototype-of-class-with-a-mapped-type?noredirect=1#comment136663010_77518782) @Daniel Respecfully — it sounds like you haven't yet provided a [mre] of your real issue. Most cases of [scope creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep) in questions are singular criterion for closure. Take some time to thoroughly think through your requirements and the details involved, and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77518782/edit) the question to relfect your conclusion.